# How to prevent lag caused by scrolling function and animation in Safari Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webkit

I want to make a website with a blurred Navigation Bar. The Navigation Bar is fixed and changes height when you start scrolling downwards. There are a few Menu Items inside the Navigation Bar, when you click one of the listet Items the Page start scrolling to the selected MenuPoint. I approached this with this function:

```
$.fn.scrollView = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
};
```

No issues so far, as I said before the height changes when you start scrolling downwards. At the top of the Page the Navigation Bar is 100px height when you scroll 100px down an animation begins and the Navigation Bar shrinks to a size of 50px. Same thing happens when you scroll to the top of the page, as soon you reached 100px the Navigation Bar gains it full height of 100px. Here is the Code:

```
var headerDown = true;
scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
var headerHeight = $('.header').height();

    if(scroll < 100){
        if(headerHeight !== 100 && headerDown === false){
            headerDown = true;
            $('.header').animate({
                height: "100px"
            }, 400);

            var menuAnimation = 100/2 - navbarHeight/2;
            $('.vcenter').animate({
                paddingTop: menuAnimation + "px"
            }, 400);
        }
    } else {
        if(headerHeight !== 50 && headerDown === true){
            headerDown = false;
            $('.header').animate({
                height: "50px"
            }, 400);

            var menuAnimation = 50/2 - navbarHeight/2 + 5;
            $('.vcenter').animate({
                paddingTop: menuAnimation + "px"
            }, 400);
        }   
    }
```

Everything works fine so far. As you can't blur through layers like in iOS 7, I used html2Canvas "http://html2canvas.hertzen.com" to make a screenshot from the side and append it to the header. Than I blur this screenshot with CSS Webkit Filter. Last thing to do I tracked the scrolling from the side and set it equal to the blurred Screenshot, so it scrolls with the site and everything behind the Navbar looks like actual side blurred.

Now my issue, when I click on one of the Menu Items the site begins to scroll. It works perfectly but as soon the site scrolls and changes height, with the blurred Canvas inside the scroll animation is very choppy and it lags like hell.

In Chrome everything works perfectly fine, but on Safari its lagging. So I started searching for the failure. I think the issue is the scroll animation and the height animation running simultan when something is actually inside the div. I think another problem is that I used overflow: hidden in CSS. I read in Blogs an the solution was to use:
 `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`

But it doesn't work fine the side is still a little bit laggy and does't track right with rendering on CPU. So I am asking for another solution.

If you need anything more please ask for it!
Thanks for your help and sorry for my english!

Comment: Have you found any fix yet, I am having the same issue here...